# When buying a new tire at car shop, they pumped the new tire and it popped loudly, is that normal?

Tags: tires, wheels, noise, tire-pressure

My ears don't hurt, but my left ear feels a little blocked afterwards. I was standing a meter and a half away  from a machine that fits rim into the tire, while also pumping air or something. The tire was lying horizontal. Anyway it popped loudly like a gunshot. Is this normal sound? I didn't like having my ear blocked. Is this permanent damage to my ear? I didn't have my ear right close to the tire but I was standing close. Is this normal when fitting new tires?

Comment: Normal as per the answer, and not likely to damage your ears...

Comment: Googled it and people say blowout caused hearing loss for them, which is why I've been concerned.

Comment: Well, any reputable shop won’t allow you that close... if you are using the cheap firm of Bodgit & Scarper Ltd then you would need to be dangerously close as the risk of flying particles etc can also be present. Are you sure you know what "blowout" is compared to the noise you describe...

Comment: No I don't know, it's a loud pop like a gunshot. I think I heard it before as a kid when Inflating balls with a pump.

Comment: Normal. No direct analog when inflating balls. Tyre "bead" (rim contact edge is stiff - with an embedded wire or cord. Look at rim profile. As tyre beads are not in their final position and have a potential energy hill to overcome in order to stretch the beads slightly to allow them to seat correct;y. When there is enough pressure the bead "climbs the wall and then crosses it an contracts into its final position. As the wall contracts and pulls home it loses stored energy - much the same a 'snapping' a rubber band. The contracting beat hits the rim with substantial force - hence the sound.

Comment: I'd wonder if the mechanic was having a bit of fun at your expense.... something like "lets scare this guy for fun" by not warning you about the loud noise.

Comment: I get now that it's normal, but after hearing it I became concerned for my left ear because the sound was piercing loud, worse than anything except for gunshot. If I stood away a little bit more it wouldn't be loud, it's just within that meter distance, because I heard it twice once when I'm a little bit away and didn't think much of it. Then second time my ear was pointed at it closer and that's when it struck me. Had my ears been pointing somewhere else it wouldve not mattered even when really close.

Comment: No it wasn't intentional but obviously won't go to that shop again, my worry is how bad it is for my ear now that I've been exposed to it.

Comment: @Altoban If your primary concern is your hearing health then go see a doctor and they will perform some tests. If you incur hearing loss then you can seek financial compensation from the tire shop for putting you in a dangerous position. If you have no further concerns about your tire then get off your keyboard and get your hearing tested.

Comment: Firstly, it is most likely you weren't meant to be in the work shop... There's probably a sign somewhere. 
Secondly, I am sorry to say but you're being dramatic. It's really not that loud, even in a small workshop, it's really not that bad. Try standing next to a large rifle when someone else is shooting, now that's a loud bang.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is absolutely normal. What's going on is they are seating the beads of the tire against the rims. In order to get them to do this, they have to over pressurize the tires a bit, which then allows the beads to ***pop*** over the sides and seat hard against the rims. This ensures they are in position correctly on the rim and promotes sealing after the fact.

Comment: Is this the same pop sound from when over inflating like a volley ball or some kind of ball using a pump? I think it sounds like that.

Comment: It's pretty loud, especially if you're standing near it and you aren't expecting it. More than enough to startle someone. Just understand, this is completely normal.

Comment: The tech should have warned you before it popped. Many techs wear earplugs, since they are less than 1.5 meters away, and doing that work regularly.

Comment: So it's normal but how bad is it for me, should I see a doc?

Comment: You'll be fine, go check a doctor if that scares you but I'm ready to bet you'll be perfectly okay.

Comment: @Altoban - I agree with others. Shouldn't be an issue, but if you feel more comfortable doing so, by all means. Also remember, this site is about car diagnostics, not human diagnostics. I'm not a doctor. I hope everything is okay with you.